# MSMQ - With IP or Hostname?

Tags: dns, ip, msmq

One of our application sends messages to the MSMQ that runs on the same server.
Code reference it this way in our Production environment (Note it uses the IP).

```
net.msmq://123.123.123.123/private/LoggingBiz/Logging.svc
```

We are building a secondary system and this part of the application did not work.
When we changed it the reference (in URL) to hostname it started working:

```
net.msmq://hostname/private/LoggingBiz/Logging.svc
```

When I was talking to the developer said that it might that the MSMQ does not use IP address. But it works in Production, so I am reluctant to accept theory.

I think it is environmental.

Can someone suggest what could have been gone wrong?

Regards,
RM

Answer (score 1):

The hostname will just be looked up to find the IP address using DNS so I think your developer is wrong.

The IP address is then used to lookup a MAC address so if the IP is not working then I suggest there is a problem with the ARP table on the machine.

you could try clearing the IP from the ARP cache:

```
arp -d <ip address>
```

Example

```
arp -d 10.1.1.2
```

Comment: oh. I tried "arp -a" and I see the right IP i used in the code as the first entry. IPCONFIG shows the same IP. That means, ARP cache is correct, right?

Comment: @Rainmaker you need to make sure that the MAC address matches to the device as well